# Difference between ActivityUnitTestCase and ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2

Tags: android, instrumentation

I am new to Android Instrumentation cases. i have been looking at the API samples and see that sometimes we use ActivityUnitTestCase and the ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2. What is the difference between the two ? When would we use one over the other ?

Answer (score 8):

See the difference discussed here:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidTesting/article.html#activity_testing

Key points:

- ActivityUnitTestCase can be used for testing layout and isolated methods.
- ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 can be used when you want to send touch/mouse events and to test state management.

Answer (score 5):

ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 class used for functional testing and ActivityUnitTestCase used for Unit testing an Activity.

Comment: Should an `ActivityUnitTestCase` be run as Unit Test or Instrumentation test?