# searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()) returns null only in test

Tags: android, testing

I have an activity with a searchview which is under test, 
Everything works as expected but the tests fail.

```
@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();

    Intent intent = new Intent(getInstrumentation().getContext(),StartActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent, null, null);               
}


@SmallTest
public void testShouldCreateStartActivity() {
    assertNotNull(activity);
}
```

The test fails because of searchManager.getSearchableInfo(activity.getComponentName()) returning null.

```
SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
SearchableInfo searchableInfo = searchManager.getSearchableInfo(activity.getComponentName());
```

Very frustrating to have working app code but the tests fail.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the test class from  **ActivityUnitTestCase** to **ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2**
and now it works.

read more about the differences here :

[Difference between ActivityUnitTestCase and ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15482282/difference-between-activityunittestcase-and-activityinstrumentationtestcase2)